# When can you adjust for (and re-allow) a disallowed year-end (December) wash-sale loss?

Tags: united-states, capital-loss, wash-sale

If you sell an entire position (e.g. 100 shares in company X) at a short-term capital loss on Dec. 10th, and your broker reports an adjusted "disallowed wash-sale loss," can you:

> a) Re-purchase the 100 shares on Feb. 25th and re-adjust (and re-allow) the loss?
>    As implied on http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8949.pdf, page 7.
>
> b) Re-purchase the 100 shares on **Jan.** 25th and re-adjust (and re-allow) the loss?
>    Some article implied the entire month of January is off-limits.
>
> c) Do (a) or (b) if, back in December, you sold only *part* (e.g. 33 shares) of your position? 
>    (and then later re-purchased just that *part.*)

Comment: If someone can tag this "form-8949" and "schedule-d" -- that would be awesome.  I don't have enough rep. to do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Disallowed losses are created when you buy a stock */- 30 days of a sale at a loss.

When you sell and have no shares left, the loss is taken. You can't have no shares and leftover disallowed loss.

Comment: What Joe is saying is that the OP has probably bought the shares already, and selling the position (at gain) will allow taking the loss.

Comment: OP said he sold entire position. If no  purchase in 30 days, the wash is used up, either to offset gain or have capital loss.

Comment: The broker *reported* a disallowed loss simply b/c shares were sold at year-end (December).  From what I understand, I can maybe 're-allow' the loss (for tax year 2013) if I prove I did not re-purchase the shares within 30 days.

Comment: Yes, you're all set. Seems the broker sets the flag for a sale at a loss anytime in December, as it can trip wash sale for a purchase in January, I'd within 30 days.